# Invoke batch file within batch file called from jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, parallel-processing

I have a batch file `a.bat` which executes `a.jar`. While `a.jar` execution is in progress, it asks to invoke `a1.bat` (consider after 25 seconds). I have used

```
@start /b cmd /c java -jar a.jar
choice /d y /t 25 > nul
@start /b cmd /c a1.bat
```

If I execute the `a.bat` from `CMD`, the `a1.bat` gets invoked.
But when `a.bat` is invoked from `jenkins`, `a1.bat` doesn't get invoked.Also the pause doesn't work. I tried using `ping 1.1.1.1` instead of `choice`, even it failed. I used @start /b to execute them in parallel. Is there any other way I can invoke the `a1.bat`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `timeout /t 25 /nobreak`? This should just pause the script for 25 seconds and then continue with submitting a1.bat.

Comment: Using this caused my build to fail directly while `a.jar` just started execution. :(